# What is the right alternative to ntpdate, wrt the below feature required?

Tags: ntpd

Since `ntpdate` has been deprecated, `ntpd -gq` serves the same purpose in most cases.
With `ntpdate`, one would receive an error

> no server suitable for synchronization found

and exit if one provides a wrong hostname/ip.

Is this feature not yet available with `ntpd` ? i.e., for `ntpd -gq` to quit if it didnt get any response from the (invalid/not running ntp) server.